# Add frame and sample size (n) to scatter plot using ggpubr in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, ggpubr

I am using the `ggscatter` function in the `ggpubr` package in R. See this code using the **mtcars** dataset as an example.

```
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(mtcars, x = "wt", y = "mpg", 
       add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
       cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
       xlab = "Weight (1000 lbs)", ylab = "Miles/(US) gallon")
```

Now, I would like to add a frame to the plot, basically adding another x and y-axis on top and bottom (without ticks or labels).

Finally, I would like to add sample size, so that the label on top shows: "R = -0.87, p = 1.3e-10, n = 32".

Could anybody help me with this, please? Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using `mtcars` just as example data, but a couple of points. There is no need for `attach()` (in fact it's discouraged), nor to create the variable `my_data`. Just `ggscatter(mtcars, ...)` is fine. Also I'd switch the x/y variables, since `mpg` is dependent on `wt` so should be the y variable.

Comment: @neilfws Thank you for those suggestions. I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for the value of `n` I have not found an elegant method to do, it may be necessary to change something in function.

```
library(ggplot2)
library("ggpubr")
ggscatter(mtcars, x = "wt", y = "mpg", 
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE, 
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Weight (1000 lbs)", ylab = "Miles/(US) gallon", 
          cor.coef.coord = c(2.5, 30)) + # c(x, y)
  + annotate("text", x = 3.53, y = 30.1, label = paste0("(n = ", nrow(mtcars), ")")) # neilfws
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. That works. However, I have a lot of these to run, so unfortunately it is not doable for me to use this solution. If anyone knows how to adjust the code to automatically include n, that would be terrific. Thank you.

Comment: If supplying the name of the data frame is an option, this small modification gets close to what you want: `+  annotate("text", x = 3.53, y = 30.1, label = paste0("(n = ", nrow(mtcars), ")"))`.

Comment: Sylvia, I edited the answer following @neilfws's suggestion. If you need to do this in more plots, please show an example of what you want there in your question.

Comment: @neilfws and bbiasi - Thank you both for your suggestions. I like this solution, but I may have rows with 'NA's. In that case, those points would be left out of the plot but still included in the 'n' and that would not be accurate. If anyone has an idea how to fix that, that would be terrific. Otherwise, I will work with your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: `nrow(na.omit(mtcars))` should fix that (or whatever the name of the dataframe is).

Comment: @neilfws - Yes, of course! That combination should do it. Thanks a million.